# Finding the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin -1x}{-7x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm studying calculus at a online course and the practice exercise came up like this:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin -1x}{-7x}$$

Now, I know that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$$

But I don't know why

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{-1x}}{-7x} = \frac{-1}{-7}$$

Comment: $\sin$ is an odd function, so ${\sin(-x)\over -7x}=(1/7){\sin x\over x}$.

Comment: Are you saying that sin(2x) = 2*sin(x) ?

Comment: No. Just that $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin{(-1x)}}{-7x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin{(x)}}{-7x}=\frac{-1}{-7}\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin{(x)}}{x}=\frac{-1}{-7} \cdot 1=\frac{1}{7}$$

Comment: You could also just directly use $$ \frac{\sin (-x)}{-7x} = \frac{1}{7} \cdot \frac{\sin (-x)}{-x} .$$

Comment: @izœc correct! But then you need to elaborate a bit more I think

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking that - it's true, but then you also need to at least note that as $x \to 0$, so does $-x$.

Comment: @izœc that's true for $x=0$ as well.. So It's not enough. What you need to do is show that the single sided limits are just "exchanged" if you use $-x$ rather than $x$

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought very deeply about that, you're right - thanks for pointing that out, that makes a lot of sense and helped eliminate some of my simplistic assumptions I didn't even realize I was making!